# О "Если ..., то ..." и "Если ..., тогда ..."

Tags: семантика

Как пояснить мальчику смысловое отличие между предложениями "Если P, то Q." и "Если P, тогда Q."?

Примечание: P и Q - пропозициональные переменные.

Comment: Вообще забавно увидеть вопрос по логике на сайте по русскому языку. Еще веселей что на вопрос правильно ответили в контексте логики и в контексте грамматики. Но на этом веселье не закончилась. Задавший вопрос по логике, после ответа в контексте грамматики интересуется: "Интересно, кто понял из ответа Софии, как объяснить мальчику смысловое отличие предложения "Если P, то Q." от предложения "Если P, тогда Q."?" Начнем с того что в логике нет понятия времени, а закончим мальчиком: он не просто бедный, он страдалец не за что))

Answer (score 2):

Мальчику надо пояснить, что смыслового различия нет. Грубо говоря, совершенно одно и то же.
Бедный мальчик...

Comment: Прочитано про "бедного мальчика".

Answer (score 0):

ЕСЛИ...ТО и ЕСЛИ...ТОГДА - это составные двухместные союзы, которые обозначают обусловленность двух высказываний. ЕСЛИ...ТО просто обозначает эту обусловленность, а ЕСЛИ...ТОГДА дополнительно сообщает о временной последовательности  этих высказываний. Также можно подчеркнуть их причинно-следственную связь: ЕСЛИ...ТО,ЗНАЧИТ

В грамматике такие слова называют коррелятами: ТО - это семантически не специализированный коррелят, а ТОГДА - имеющий такую специализацию.

Comment: Спасибо за предоставленные сведения.

Comment: Интересно, после ответа Софии Галактион понял, как это объяснить мальчику?

Comment: Интересно, кто понял из ответа Софии, как объяснить мальчику смысловое отличие предложения "Если P, то Q." от предложения "Если P, тогда Q."?